# Why can SMTP APIs use any from address? How can I blacklist my email?

Tags: smtp, sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid's SMTP API, and I realized that I can set the from address to any email.

I find this concerning. It's very clear that anybody with an SMTP API could just start sending emails pretending to be me.

Is there a way I can add my email or a group of emails to an "SMTP Blacklist"?

```
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

message = Mail(
    from_email='any@from.email',
    to_emails='any@to.email',
    subject='Title',
    html_content='Hello world')
try:
    sg = SendGridAPIClient('FREE_API_KEY')
    response = sg.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on DMARC and SPF Records. These two "solutions" make it much more difficult for unauthorized email to get delivered successfully.

EDIT: Also read up on DKIM.